# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall' in Prefect

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, process-monitoring, prefect

I have been using the following code in production for the last couple of months,

```
@task
def sql_run_procs():
    """This is a delete and update..."""
    # Get our logger
    logger = prefect.utilities.logging.get_logger()  # type: ignore

    conn = connect_db(prefect.config.kv.p.prod_db_constring, logger)  ## wrapper around create_engine()

    with conn.connect() as con:
        try:
            r = con.execute(
                f"EXECUTE fs.spETL_MyProc '{prefect.config.kv.p.staging_db_name}'"
            ).fetchall()
            for q in r[0]:
                if q == 1:
                    logger.info(f"Query {q} has failed")
                    raise signals.FAIL()
        except :
            raise SQLAlchemyError("Error in SQL Script")
```

So like any good coder I copy and pasted the code into another script

```
@task
def sql_run_procs():
    """This is a clean, truncate and insert"""
    # Get our logger
    logger = prefect.utilities.logging.get_logger()  # type: ignore

    conn = connect_db(prefect.config.kv.p.prod_db_constring, logger)

    with conn.connect() as con:
        try:
            r = con.execute(
                f"EXECUTE forms.spETL_MyOtherProc '{prefect.config.kv.p.staging_db_name}'"
            ).fetchall()
            for q in r[0]:
                if q == 1:
                    logger.info(f"Query {q} has failed")
                    raise signals.FAIL()
        except :
            raise SQLAlchemyError("Error in SQL Script")
```

And got the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'

The only difference other than the name of the stored procedure is they're in different Prefect projects. I've searched this site and others for a possible solution but had no success. I know that it's probably something staring me right in the face but after an hour and a half... you know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `forms.spETL_MyOtherProc` return a result set? It seems that it does not.

Comment: Yes the procedure returns an integer for each query with 0 or 1 set in variables in try catch, the proc works fine on it's own and nocount is set to off.

Comment: `set nocount off` means that it will be returning row counts with no columns for your insert operation (mentioned in your Python comments).